# Insert a transformed integer_sequence into a variadic template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

How do you insert a transformed `integer_sequence` (or similar since I am targeting C++11) into a variadic template argument?

For example I have a class that represents a set of bit-wise flags (shown below). It is made using a nested-class because you cannot have two variadic template arguments for the same class. It would be used like `typedef Flags<unsigned char, FLAG_A, FLAG_B, FLAG_C>::WithValues<0x01, 0x02, 0x04> MyFlags`. Typically, they will be used with the values that are powers of two (although not always, in some cases certain combinations would be made, for example one could imagine a set of flags like Read=0x1, Write=0x2, and ReadWrite=0x3=0x1|0x2). I would like to provide a way to do `typedef Flags<unsigned char, FLAG_A, FLAG_B, FLAG_C>::WithDefaultValues MyFlags`.

```
template<class _B, template <class,class,_B> class... _Fs>
class Flags
{
public:
    template<_B... _Vs>
    class WithValues :
      public _Fs<_B, Flags<_B,_Fs...>::WithValues<_Vs...>, _Vs>...
    {
        // ...
    };
};
```

I have tried the following without success (placed inside the Flags class, outside the WithValues class):

```
private:
    struct _F {
        // dummy class which can be given to a flag-name template
        template <_B _V> inline constexpr
        explicit _F(std::integral_constant<_B, _V>) { } };

        // we count the flags, but only in a dummy way
        static constexpr unsigned _count = sizeof...(_Fs<_B, _F, 1>); 

        static inline constexpr
        _B pow2(unsigned exp, _B base = 2, _B result = 1) {
            return exp < 1 ?
                    result :
                    pow2(exp/2,
                         base*base,
                         (exp % 2) ? result*base : result);
        }

    template <_B... _Is>  struct indices          {
        using next = indices<_Is..., sizeof...(_Is)>;
        using WithPow2Values = WithValues<pow2(_Is)...>;
    };
    template <unsigned N> struct build_indices    {
        using type = typename build_indices<N-1>::type::next;
    };
    template <>           struct build_indices<0> {
        using type = indices<>;
    };

    //// Another attempt
    //template <            _B... _Is> struct indices {
    //    using WithPow2Values = WithValues<pow2(_Is)...>;
    //};
    //template <unsigned N, _B... _Is> struct build_indices            
    //                   : build_indices<N-1, N-1, _Is...> { };
    //template <            _B... _Is> struct build_indices<0, _Is...> 
    //                                         : indices<_Is...>       { };

public:
    using WithDefaultValues =
            typename build_indices<_count>::type::WithPow2Values;
```

Of course, I would be willing to have any other alternatives to the whole situation (supporting both flag names and values in the same template set, etc).

I have included a "working" example at ideone: http://ideone.com/NYtUrg - by "working" I mean compiles fine without using default values but fails with default values (there is a #define to switch between them).

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with underscore then a capital letter.   Those are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard libraries).

Comment: Thanks. Are you also implying that underscore - lowercase letter okay?  I am using underscores to avoid problems with flag-names clashing with 'internally' used names of the flags class.

Comment: @coderforlife As for the underscores, just put them backwards to avoid breaking standard rules, e.g `B_` instead of `_B`. It's easy :P ...

Comment: didn’t read the whole post. Just a remark on: `It is made using a nested-class because you cannot have two variadic template arguments for the same class`. Actually you can using tuple: `template <class... Args1, class... Args2> class X<std::tuple<Args1...>, std::tuple<Args2...>`. Again, didn’t read the question, sorry about that, but maybe this helps you simplify the design.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, however it will not work here since one variadic template is not a class/typename pack but an integral pack (hence unpacking an integer sequence). I guess one could make a tuple-like class to support it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out on my own, I guess I posted too soon.

I was able to get around the error generated with the given code with a dummy template argument in the `build_indices` and `indices` template classes above. The argument has to be a typename as they currently have variadic integral types.

(Note: still using the improper `_F` names here - I have corrected my personal code to not use these reserved name - thanks for the tip)

Here is a working solution which results in the `WithValues<...>` template to be filled with powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...) based on the size of the Flags variadic template.

```
private:
// dummy class which can be given to a flag-name template
struct _F
{
    template <_B _V> inline constexpr
    explicit _F(std::integral_constant<_B, _V>) { }
};

// we count the flags, but only in a dummy way
static constexpr unsigned _count = sizeof...(_Fs<_B, _F, 1>); 

static inline constexpr
_B pow2(unsigned exp, _B base = 2, _B result = 1)
{
    return exp < 1 ?
            result :
            pow2(exp/2, base*base, (exp % 2) ? result*base : result);
}

template <class dummy, _B... _Is>  struct indices
{
    using next = indices<dummy, _Is..., sizeof...(_Is)>;
    using WithPow2Values = WithValues<pow2(_Is)...>;
};
template <class dummy, unsigned N> struct build_indices
{
    using type = typename build_indices<dummy, N-1>::type::next;
};
template <class dummy> struct build_indices<dummy, 0>
{
    using type = indices<dummy>;
};

public:
using WithDefaultValues =
        typename build_indices<void, _count>::type::WithPow2Values;
```